# Weird signal handler behavior when invoking mremap(2)

Tags: c, gcc, signals

Firstly, here is the code

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h> /* mmap() is defined in this header */
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#define FILE_NAME "mremap_test_file.txt"

void sighandler(int signum) {
    printf("Signal SIGSEGV recieved\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{


    //int fdin;
    int fdout = 0;
    static char stack[SIGSTKSZ];
    stack_t ss = {
        .ss_size = SIGSTKSZ,
        .ss_sp = stack,
    };
    struct sigaction sigact;
    sigaltstack(&ss, 0);
    int ret = sigaction(SIGSEGV, NULL, &sigact);
    if (ret == -1){
        perror("register sighandler");
        return -1;
    }
    sigact.sa_handler = sighandler;
    sigact.sa_flags |= SA_ONSTACK | SA_RESTART;
    ret = sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sigact, NULL);
    if (ret == -1){
        perror("register sighandler");
        return -1;
    }

    fdout = open(FILE_NAME, O_CREAT| O_RDWR);
    if( fdout < 0){

        perror("open");
        return -1;
    }
    char test_str[1024];
    memset(test_str,65,1024);
    write(fdout,test_str,1024);
    close(fdout);
    sync();
    if(argc > 2)
        return 0;
    fdout = open(FILE_NAME, O_CREAT| O_RDWR);
    if( fdout < 0){

        perror("open");
        return -1;
    }

    void * addr = NULL;
    addr = mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_EXEC |PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fdout, 0);

    if(addr == MAP_FAILED ){
        perror("mmap");
        return -1;
    }
    void* remap_addr = addr;
    remap_addr = mremap(remap_addr, 1024, 512, (MREMAP_FIXED | MREMAP_MAYMOVE), (void*)((unsigned long)remap_addr + 4096) );
    if(remap_addr == MAP_FAILED){
        perror("mremap");
        return -1;
    }
    int a = *(int*)(0);

    remove(FILE_NAME);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) to compile this code

You can see there is `int a = *(int*)(0);` inside the code to trigger SIGSEGV. The weird thing is, if this line of code run before `mremap(2)` the custom SIGSEGV handler got triggered; if this line of code run after `mremap(2)` it trigger the default SIGSEGV handler.

The `mremap(2)` do return success without any problem, so that I couldn't understand those such behavior

[image: First case]
[image: 2nd case]

I also tried to another case, and found out this
[image: 3rd case]
It is seem that both default and custome handler is called

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing that behaviour, in *both* cases the illegal access causes a call to `sighandler()`.

Of course, that *may* be because I had to fix a couple of problems with your code (what you provided did not compile out of the box), specifically:

- creating the files with permissions that let me open them again since they otherwise get created with permission mask zero:
  `fdout = open(FILE_NAME, O_CREAT| O_RDWR, 0777);`
- Re-mapping based on the original address rather than the as-yet-non-existent remapped address:
  `void *remap_addr = mremap(addr, 1024, 512, (MREMAP_FIXED | MREMAP_MAYMOVE), (void*)((unsigned long)addr + 4096) );`

Once those problems were fixed, the illegal access called the custom handler whether or not it was before or after the `mremap`. If that doesn't fix your problem, I suggest you post your *actual* code that causes the issue :-)

---

Another thing you may want to consider is that `printf` is *not* one of the functions that's considered safe to call from signal handlers. [This link](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) details what is safe to use, so it *may* be that this is being caused by an issue inside the `printf` itself.

---

As an aside, it would be interesting to see what happens if you install (or re-install) the signal handler *after* the remapping. I only mention that because there have been other cases where calling certain functions has interfered with what was originally thought to be a separate item (a vague memory of a conflict between `sleep` and the `SIGALRM` signal, but this was a *long* time ago).

---

The only other thing I could suggest is that you use `sigaction` to get the current disposition of the signal following the `mremap` call. If it's been detached from your handler for some reason, that should hopefully make that clear.

Comment: I added evidence to my question. Based on mremap behavior, they should move the existence memory to the destination memory, which will allocate the memory in that location, I chose the memory with +0x1000 offset to prevent overriding the existed memory

Comment: And also, that is the full code without debug printf. about permission, I use root user, so I totally forgot that part; but I do not think that was a problem

Comment: I have tested with removing printf in signal handler, but that not help, the behavior keeps the same. Also re-install the signal handler won't help neither.

Comment: @Silver, I'm assuming you mean that re-installing the handler *didn't* help (in that you tried it and it made no difference) rather than *won't* help (meaning you didn't even bother trying) :-)

Comment: @Silver, it might then be useful to post your OS/platform details. My tests worked but they were done with Ubuntu 18.04 running under WSL1.

Comment: I did. in the original question. <gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)>

Comment: for more information, here is my `uname -a` "Linux ***** 4.4.0-174-generic #204-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 29 06:41:01 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
"

Comment: my upvote for that your sugestion lead me to the core of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have debug a little more about this. It is seem that when invoking syscall `mmap(2)`, the system chose address belong to program's stack for allocation. And program's stack address grow downward. So if I try to `mremap(2)` to `addr + 4096` it will override some illegal segment of program's memory. This illegal allocation caused by kernel `do_unmap` on `addr` and `addr + 4096` then `move_vma` on to this address. (Reference https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.18.140/source/mm/mremap.c#L406)

So when `MREMAP_FIXED` is specified when calling `mremap(2)`do not care if *`new_address`* parameter could violate its program's address space.

A possible workaround for this is, instead of remap to `addr + 4096`, remap to `addr - 4096`

```
remap_addr = mremap(remap_addr, 1024, 512, (MREMAP_FIXED | MREMAP_MAYMOVE), (void*)((unsigned long)remap_addr - 4096) );
```

Comment: @paxdiablo fyi. Btw, if i call `sigaction()` to see if my handler got detached, i got SIGSEGV when trying to access the `sa_handler`. So my guess is the handler do not got detached, but the pointer to it function got dereferenced. The default handler is called because of the program trying to call illegal function pointer.